# Alternatives to using nested for loops to flatten data structure

Tags: python, loops, data-structures, nested

I have a nested data structure with: a list of dicts contained many levels into a dictionary. For example:

```
{‘L1’:
    ‘L2’:
        {‘L3’: [{‘a’: 1, ‘b’: 2}, {‘c’: 1, ‘d’: 2}]}
  Etc …
}
```

I would like an output like which flattens the inner list of list, with the outer elements at each level. E.g.

L1, L2, L3, a,1, b,2

L1, L2, L3, c,1, d,2

Etc …

Instead of using a nested for loop, is there a more ‘pythonic’ and efficient way of achieving the result?

Nested for loops, which works but slow when the data structure is large

Comment: Remember to turn off "smart quotes" when copying and pasting code.

Comment: `[‘a’: 1, ‘b’: 2]` is not valid. `key: value` syntax is only allowed in dictionaries, not lists.

Comment: Check `itertools` to see if it has any functions that do what you want.

Comment: [itertools.chain()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) is probably what you are looking for

Comment: "Nested for loops, which works but slow when the data structure is large" there is no choice to traverse every element if you want every element. Nested loops are not *inherently* slow, and this is the fastest way to do what you want to be doing, algorithmically.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a recursive function:

```
from itertools import chain
from typing import Iterator, Optional, Union


def flatten(
    d: dict,
    keys: Optional[list[Union[str, int]]] = None
) -> Iterator[list[Union[str, int]]]:
  """Recursively flattens a nested dictionary structure into a list of lists.

     Args:
       d: The input nested dictionary to flatten.
       keys: A list of keys from the parent dictionaries. 

     Yields:
       Iterator[list[Union[str, int]]]: A list containing the flattened elements.
  """
  if keys is None:
    keys = []
  for k, v in d.items():
    new_keys = keys + [k]
    if isinstance(v, dict):
      yield from flatten(v, new_keys)
    elif isinstance(v, list):
      for item in v:
        flattened_items = chain.from_iterable(item.items())
        yield new_keys + list(flattened_items)
    else:
      yield new_keys + [v]


def main() -> None:
  data = {'L1': {'L2': {'L3': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 1, 'd': 2}]}}}
  for item in flatten(data):
    print(*item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**Output:**

```
L1 L2 L3 a 1 b 2
L1 L2 L3 c 1 d 2
```

Comment: why? Is this faster?

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is the performance of nested loops, you may want to consider a different model for your data structure because there will be some form of nesting going on no matter how you approach it.

If the issue is with the varying number of levels, then recursion is probably your best bet (although it will be slower than nested loops).

Here is a recursive generator that will output each line without creating a whole (flattened) copy of the structure:

```
def flatItems(d,path=[]):
    if isinstance(d,list):
        for k,v in enumerate(d,1):
            yield from flatItems(v,path+[k])
    elif isinstance(d,dict):
        for k,v in d.items():
            yield from flatItems(v,path+[k])
    else:
        yield path + [d]
```

output:

```
data = {'L1': {'L2': {'L3': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 1, 'd': 2}]}}}

print(*flatItems(data),sep="\n")

['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 1, 'a', 1]
['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 1, 'b', 2]
['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 2, 'c', 1]
['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 2, 'd', 2]
```

*Note that, based on you example, I used 1-based indexes for lists.  Python's list indexing is zero-based, you may want to revisit that as well.*